# int Main() not giving any output

Tags: c++

I have been working on a project for my computer science course and I'm having a problem running my Stack implementation file using CPP in vs code (g++). the problem is this file is not giving any output to console.

main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myStack.h"

using namespace std;

stackType<int> sortStack(stackType<int> input) 
{ 
    stackType<int> tmpStack; 

    while (!input.isEmptyStack()) { 
        int tmp = input.top(); 
        input.pop(); 

        while (!tmpStack.isEmptyStack() && tmpStack.top() > tmp) { 

            input.push(tmpStack.top()); 
            tmpStack.pop(); 
        } 

        tmpStack.push(tmp); 
    } 
    return tmpStack;
} 

stackType<int> sortedMerge(stackType<int> s1, stackType<int> s2) 
{ 
    stackType<int> res; 
    while (!s1.isEmptyStack()) { 
        res.push(s1.top()); 
        s1.pop(); 
    } 
    while (!s2.isEmptyStack()) { 
        res.push(s2.top()); 
        s2.pop(); 
    } 

    return sortStack(res); 
} 

// main function 
int main() 
{ 
    stackType<int> stack1, stack2; 
    stack1.push(34); 
    stack1.push(3); 
    stack1.push(31); 
    stack2.push(1); 
    stack2.push(12); 
    stack2.push(23); 

    stackType<int> tmpStack = sortedMerge(stack1, stack2); 
    cout << "Sorted and merged stack :\n"; 

    while(!tmpStack.isEmptyStack()){ 
        cout << tmpStack.top() << " "; 
        tmpStack.pop(); 
    } 
}
```

**Note: there is a header file containing stackType which I included as "myStack.h" and another one for virtual's

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I would assume, based on your problem description, that `sortedMerge` never returns. Looking at `sortStack` I see several potential infinite loops. You should try to debug your code.

Comment: why are these two functions not templated?

Comment: And if possible, can you include the `mystack.h` header?

Comment: SO is not a debug service or a program service where you expect use to write a valid `stack` template implementation. Give us the debug error you have and all the needed code

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't know how to debug my c++ we haven't ever heard about this at university but I will still manage to learn how to. also I've just tried to run my code in sublime text and it worked perfectly so I'm really confused why isn't vs code not showing any output.

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying, but after trying the code in a different IDE it worked perfectly so I guess the problem is vs code?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah and its because the education system is the worse in the country I'm studying in especially in computer departments. But I'm interested in computer science so I usually learn stuff on my own.